# php create array with my sqli query and not array of objects

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make an array with the result of a mysql query but instead I'm making an array of objects.

Have unsuccessfully tried to convert the array of objects into an array, is that the best approach?

```
echo json_decode(json_encode($iconsArray), true); // didnt work
```

This is my query

```
function listIcons(){
  global $link;
  $queryAssets = "SELECT DISTINCT icon_1,icon_2,icon_3,icon_4 FROM icons";
  $resultqueryAssets = mysqli_query($link, $queryAssets) or 
  die(mysqli_error($link));

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultqueryAssets)) {

    $iconsArray[] = $row;
  }

  $allIcons = json_encode($iconsArray);
  echo $allIcons;
  return array($allIcons);
}
```

allIcons outout is

```
$allIcons = [
  0:{icon_1: "01_a", icon_2: "01_b", icon_3: "01_c", icon_4: "01_d"}
  1{icon_1: "02_a", icon_2: "02_b", icon_3: "02_c", icon_4: "02_d"}
]
```

And the output that I need but cant achieve

```
$allIcons = [
  0:"01_a"
  1:"02_a"
  2:"01_b"
  3:"02_b"
  4:"03_a"
  5:"02_b"
  ...
]
```

Comment: Can you perhaps sync your desired output data with your current resultset output?  This will improve question clarity for future researchers.

Comment: It looks like you want the sorting order to be a flattened transposed array.  In simpler words, you want to extract the four columns of data from your resultset and then merge those collections into a one dimensional indexed array.  If you need a hand with that, you can ask arkascha or me.  This aspect of your question is built into your original post and is not rude to seek support for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is the easiest thing to do:

```
<?php
// ....
$queryAssets = "SELECT DISTINCT icon_1,icon_2,icon_3,icon_4 FROM icons";
$resultqueryAssets = mysqli_query($link, $queryAssets) or 
die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultqueryAssets)) {
    foreach ($row as $icon) {
        $icons[] = $icon;
    }
}
var_dump($icons);
```

An alternative without an additional loop would be such thing:

```
<?php
// ....
$queryAssets = "SELECT DISTINCT icon_1,icon_2,icon_3,icon_4 FROM icons";
$resultqueryAssets = mysqli_query($link, $queryAssets) or 
die(mysqli_error($link));

$icons = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultqueryAssets)) {
    $icons = array_merge($icons, array_values($row));
}
var_dump($icons);
```

Actually things get easier if you don't fetch an associative array at all:

```
<?php
// ....
$queryAssets = "SELECT DISTINCT icon_1,icon_2,icon_3,icon_4 FROM icons";
$resultqueryAssets = mysqli_query($link, $queryAssets) or 
die(mysqli_error($link));

$icons = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultqueryAssets)) {
    $icons = array_merge($icons, $row);
}
var_dump($icons);
```

---

*I did not run these code snippets, just typed them down. I hope there is no silly typo in them...*